# Calculate $\iint x^2y^2\,dy\,dx$ over the region $R$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$\iint_R x^2y^2\,dy\,dx$$

I have to solve the above integral over the region $R$ defined by:

$R$ is the region enclosed by the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and below the line $y=x+1$.

These give me the regions of:

$$\left\{(x,y) \mid -1 \le  x \le 0, -\sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le  x + 1 ∪ 0 \le  x \le  1, -\sqrt{1-x^2} \le  y \le  \sqrt{1-x^2}\right\}$$

Doing the integration for the above problem leave me with an absurdly large second integral, that's not impossible to solve but extremely lengthy.

$$\frac{1}{3}\int x^2(x+1)^3+x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2} + \frac{2}{3}\int x^2(1-x^2)^{3/2}$$

Surely there must be a simpler way?

Alternatively, I've completely botched this and none of this is nearly as complicated as I've made it which is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the area into the triangle in the second quadrant and the rest of the circle. Use the transform to polar coordinates on the second area.
$$
\iint_Rx^2y^2dydx=\int_{-1}^0\int_0^{x+1}x^2y^2dydx+\int_0^1\int_{-\pi}^{\frac\pi2}\rho^5\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi d\phi d\rho
$$
And now it's straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't actually done the polar coordinates conversion before so this was a nice check while I was learning it.